# Logout banned users

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

im banning users using the following:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
if (user != null)
{
    user.IsApproved = false;
    user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
    Membership.UpdateUser(user);
}
```

if the user is currently logged in they can still do things on the site, so how can i also log them off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your global.asax you can do something like this..

```
Application_OnAuthenticateReuqest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!UserHasAccess())
  {
     FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  }
}

private bool UserHasAccess()
{
   var user = Membership.GetUser(Context.User.Identity);

   return user.isApproved;
}
```

You may want to consider some form of caching...

And btw I am assuming you're using proper [Authorize] attributes on your controller methods.

Comment: `Global.asax` sounds like the best place for this, next best would probably be a master page `page_load` I would imagine.

Comment: Upvoted.  This is basically how I handle the same issue (though I am using MVC3 so its different) and it works well.  The downside is that I do need to check on every request if the user has been disabled by checking the database.   

The only way I see you caching it would be if your member update method is actually updating the cache itself and your authorization method checked said cache.

Comment: See @Bryan's comment.  The constant db access might be costly.  If it was you'd probably want to cache each persons isApproved and then have your update user mechanism update the cache as well.

Comment: If that becomes a bottleneck, you could possibly store the user information in a cache of some sort (memcached, velocity, session storage even) with a TTL of, say, 5 minutes so that you would only check the DB once every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check on pageLoad of every request the users' status.  If they are banned you can simply `response.End()` or `response.Redirect()` them to the home page.

Comment: I understand this, but a response.End() will at least prevent the user retrieving any more content.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to validate whether the user has been banned on every request. You could achieve this using the HttpApplication (Global.asax) or preferably using a custom HttpModule.